# packages for spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I am new to spring framework. I am practicing spring example in Eclipse IDE, I like to know what all plugins  I need to install to get started with spring framework.
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4):

You don't really *need* any plugin. You can just write your code.

But you can use the [Spring tool suite](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts) or Spring-IDE plugin.

---

**Resources :**

- [STS FAQs](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=75980)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing mandatory. But still, your best option is probably to use [SpringSource Tool Suite (STS)](http://www.springsource.com/developer/sts), an Eclipse based distro tailored for Spring development. From its website:

> SpringSource Tool Suite™ (STS) provides the best Eclipse-powered development environment for building Spring-powered enterprise applications. STS includes tools for all of the latest enterprise Java, Spring, Groovy and Grails based technologies as well as the most advanced tooling available for enterprise OSGi development. STS supports application targeting to local, virtual and cloud-based servers and provides built in support for SpringSource tc Server. SpringSource Tool Suite is freely available for development and internal business operations use with no time limits.

STS comes with the following additional features preinstalled:

- M2Eclipse for Maven integration
- Extensive Spring tooling support for all Spring Portfolio projects
- Spring Roo integration
- Groovy support (optional)
- and more

Comment: I'd say it's almost mandatory :-) I'd never go back to Spring Development without STS (+1)

Answer (score 1):

There is also spring source toolkit which is a version of eclipse that comes with the plugin installed. http://www.springsource.com/developer/stsv

While you don't *need* a plugin you will need the spring libraries http://www.springsource.org/download